Theorems on several variables and applications
Find the minimum/maximum value of $$f(x, y) = 2x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2$$
subject to the constraint curve $C$, $x + y = 6$
I don't have a knack for these kind of questions. Should I substitute $y=6-x$ in the original expression and then find the min and Max, or is it wrong?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Lagrange multiplier is the way.

@Leonardo i strongly believe that OP isn't familiar with that

Yes, you can just plug in $y = 6 - x$ to the original expression

Yes, after substituting $~y = 6-x,~$ create the single variable function $~f(x),~$ to represent the expression $~2x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2.~$  Then, determine the minimum and maximum value of $~f(x),~$ on the interval $~0 \leq x \leq 6,~$ by examining $~f(0), ~f(6),~$ the behavior of $~f'(x),~$ on the interval $~0 \leq x \leq 6,~$ and (perhaps, if needed), the corresponding behavior of $~f''(x).$

Please see this article on MathSE protocol.

We will rewrite the expression $$f(x,y)=2x^2+2xy+3y^2$$
$$=2(x^2+y^2+2xy)+y^2-2xy$$
$$=2(x+y)^2+y^2-2xy$$
$$=y^2-2xy+72$$
Define $$g(x,y)=y^2-2xy$$
Put $y=6-x$ in the above expression, and we'll get $$3(y^2-4y)$$
This function is increasing for $y>2$ and decreasing for $y<2$ which implies that the minimum of this function will occur at $y=2$ and the maximum will occur at $y=\lim_{a\to\infty}a$
This clearly means that there is no global maximum.
So $$\operatorname{min}\{3y^2-12y\}=-12$$
Hence $$\operatorname{min}\{f(x,y)\}=-12+72=60$$
